# Как в PHP сделать фоновый рисунок "точечным"? (прикрепил файл)

Tags: php

Как в PHP можно добиться такого эффекта в background image? [image]

**UPD:**
Хотя бы скажите как такое называется, чтобы вбить в поиск???

Answer (score 1):

а еще можно просто поверх наложить прозрачную сетку с нужным вам узором

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < image.Width; i+=2)
  for(int j = 0; j < image.Height; j+=2)
    drawPoint(i, j, color);
```

Принцип таков, а библиотеку использовать, так это какую изволите.

Comment: амм, я чет не могу найти ничего про drawPoint. Везде drawLine. Вы правильно указали??? И еще, значение "color" так и оставить или туда написать какой нибудь цвет? @decyrus

Comment: Это я к примеру. Вот например imagesetpixel:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagesetpixel.php
Там множество примеров.